# Parsing LuisResult to get JSON fields

Tags: c#, json, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm learning about Microsoft's Bot Framework using LUIS. I'm trying to make a simple math bot that will understand math phrases. When the user types "what is two plus three" or anything similar, LUIS understands that the person wants to add two and three. The result is a LuisResult looks like this:

```
{
  "query": "what is one plus three",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "addition",
    "score": 0.999997139
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "addition",
      "score": 0.999997139
    },
{
  "intent": "None",
  "score": 0.03979478
}
],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "one",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 8,
      "endIndex": 10,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "1"
    }
    },
    {
      "entity": "three",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 17,
      "endIndex": 21,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract both of the "value" fields from the entities list. At the moment I only know how to extract the first entity "one" by doing

```
string numberResult = "";
EntityRecommendation rec;
if(result.TryFindEntity("builtin.number", out rec))
{
     numberResult = rec.Entity;
     this.number = Int32.Parse(numberResult);
 }
```

Is there any way to extract both of the value fields "1" and "3" from this?

Answer (score 2):

[LuisResult](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/LuisResult.cs) has a [list of all the detected Entities](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/LuisResult.cs#L60). You can just iterate over them instead of using the `TryFindEntity` method.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to c# how would I iterate over the IList of entities to get to the values? @EzequielJadib

Comment: u can iterate using for loop in C#.

Comment: Sorry to clarify, I understand how to iterate, I'm still unsure how I access the "values" field in the entity. It's something like

var valuesEntity = result.Entities;

int i = 0;

foreach (var name in valuesEntity){

await context.PostAsync($"{valuesEntity[i]}");

i++;

}

Comment: I recall correctly the Entity property will containe the value of the entity.

Comment: I'm looking for the "values" field not the value of the entity
      "entity": "three",
      "type": "builtin.number",
      "startIndex": 17,
      "endIndex": 21,
      "resolution": {
        "value": "3"
      }
the last field in the json entity

Comment: Sorry to ask so much. This is what I'm using to try to get values. var valuesEntity = result.Entities; var value = valuesEntity[i].Resolution.Values;
I try to parse it to an int32 but crashes the program. Any suggestions?

Comment: I answered in the other thread. Please mark this as answered/upvote